# Run Jupyter Notebook From External Drive (Windows)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've looked around and I can't find an answer for my situation. I keep my notebooks on an external drive and I've had to copy them from my work computer to the drive, then to another computer when I have to move.
How can I just open a notebook from the external drive? I'd like to keep it simple and just have one external drive where I work from and keep everything. Working in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! Running the code below in powershell works fine. Created a file in text editor and saved it as a .ps1 file.

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:
```